# Change timeout for specific mappings?

Tags: vim

I have some hackish convenience mappings to write common unicode characters. These are always done in a very fast sequence, and I would like the timeout for these to be a lot shorter than for my normal mappings.

Is there a way to have a timeout per remap? The help for `timeout` and friends doesn't give me high confidence, but I know there are many tricks out there.

For example

```
" should have normal timeout
inoremap <leader>f somecommand
" should have a short timeout
inoremap oe ø
```

Comment: what is problem? please show me example.

Answer (score 0):

Insert mode mappings where subsets are also typed are indeed bad because of the noticeable delay until the (incomplete mapping) characters are inserted. It's best to avoid those.

There's a built-in way to insert Unicode characters, see `:help digraph`. For your example character, that can be entered via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>. If you like to keep your shortcut, redefine as such:

```
:digraph oe 248
```

Comment: It's exactly to save number of keypresses I need this. I agree it's not a good practice, but `<c-k>o/` is worse than my current situation of `<rightshift>o/` that I'm using everywhere. The problem is that some characters are used a lot in my native tongue, æøå, but I'm using a keyboard layout without these characters. The `imap` + `iabbrev` (to correct some words like `nø` to `noe` - currently 5000 words) works, but as you say, it's noticeable delay.

Comment: I personally also use digraphs (for German umlauts); they're not as frequent, but I manage to type them quite fast. Try it - I got used to it soon. Alternatively, look into `<A-o>` mappings; they don't interfere, have few keypresses, but are harder to type.

Comment: Karat: <A-o> as in <alt-o> for ø? I've been using the digraphs solution (with <rightshift>o/) for a year at least, and I still find it difficult to type. And unfortunately, it's very frequent in Norwegian. I think I'll try my new setup for a while. I might get used to it even though I don't find it a very elegant solution.

Comment: Yes (if the Alt mappings work in your terminal (they should in GVIM)). If it's just one or two characters, there are a few Ctrl-combinations unused in insert mode, e.g. `<C-g>`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the same problem - adding Unicode characters via shortcuts - I use a vim keymap file. In ~/.vim/keymap/aaaaa_utf-8.vim and in ~/.vim/keymap_aaaaa.vim I have:

```
    " short keymap name for statusline  (I did't really write 'aaaaa')
    let b:keymap_name = "aaaaa"

    scriptencoding utf8

    loadkeymap

    ;c <char-0xe7>
    ;C <char-0xc7>
    ;g <char-0x11f>
    ;G <char-0x11e>
    ;i <char-0x131>
    ;I <char-0x130>
    ;o <char-0xf6>
    ;O <char-0xd6>
    ;s <char-0x15f>
    ;S <char-0x15e>
    ;u <char-0xfc>
    ;U <char-0xdc>
```

and then in my vimrc I have

```
set keymap=aaaaa
```

I now, habitually, without thinking, type ;C and Ç appears. I type at a good speed and I have never noticed a delay: there is no delay as I type.

As an added bonus, I use these same shortcuts on the bash command line, via

```
    ";c": "\xc3\xa7"
    ";C": "\xc3\xb7"    
    ";g": "\xc4\x9f"
    ";G": "\xc4\x93"
    ";i": "\xc4\xb1"
    ";I": "\xc4\xb0"
    ";o": "\xc3\xb6"
    ";O": "\xc3\x96"
    ";s": "\xC5\x9F"
    ";S": "\xC5\x9E"
    ";u": "\xc3\xbc"
    ";U": "\xc3\x9c"
```

added to my .inputrc

For reference:

```
      Ç     ç     Ğ     ğ     İ     ı     Ö     ö     Ş     ş     Ü     ü
Code: 00c7  00e7  011e  011f  0130  0131  00d6  00f6  015e  015f  00dc  00fc
UTF8: c3 87 c3 a7 c4 9e c4 9f c4 b0 c4 b1 c3 96 c3 b6 c5 9e c5 9f c3 9c c3 bc
```